# How to increment django DB using cookies

Tags: python, django, cookies, session-cookies

I am trying to increment my DB by 1 if a user has not visited that unique item.pk before. At the moment it will only increment by 1 for all items in my DB, id like to to increment by 1 for each item.pk in the DB.

The view is to Create a view that returns a single bug object based on the bug ID (pk) and render it to the bug_detail.html template or return 404 error if object is not found Also handles commenting on the bug as well as regulating the amount of views attributed to the bug.

```
def bug_detail(request, pk):

bug = get_object_or_404(Bug, pk=pk)
if request.method == "POST":

    form = BugCommentForm(request.POST)

    if form.is_valid():
        bugComment = form.save(commit=False)
        bugComment.bug = bug
        bugComment.author = request.user
        bug.comment_number += 1
        bug.save()
        bugComment.save()
        return redirect(reverse('bug_detail', kwargs={'pk': pk}))
    else:
        messages.error(
            request,
            "Looks like your comment is empty!",
            extra_tags="alert-danger")
        form = BugCommentForm(instance=bug)
        return redirect(reverse('bug_detail', kwargs={'pk': pk}))

else:
    form = BugCommentForm()
    comments = BugComment.objects.filter(bug__pk=bug.pk)
    comments_total = len(comments)
    response = render(request,
                      'bug_detail.html',
                      {'bug': bug,
                       'comments': comments,
                       'comments_total': comments_total,
                       'form': form})
    if 'last_visit' in request.COOKIES and 'bugg' in request.COOKIES:
        last_visit = request.COOKIES['last_visit']
        # the cookie is a string - convert back to a datetime type
        last_visit_time = datetime.strptime(
            last_visit[:-7], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
        curr_time = datetime.now()
        if (curr_time - last_visit_time).days > 0:
            # if at least one day has gone by then inc the views count.
            response.set_cookie('last_visit', datetime.now())
            bug.views += 1
            bug.save()
    elif 'bugg' not in request.COOKIES:
        response.set_cookie('last_visit', datetime.now())
        response.set_cookie('bugg', bug.pk)
        bug.views += 1
        bug.save()
    else:
        response.set_cookie('last_visit', datetime.now())
        response.set_cookie('bugg', bug.pk)
        bug.views += 1
        bug.save()
    return response
```

Comment: So what is wrong with this code? And why are you using cookies directly, rather than the session framework?

Comment: So at the moment when i visit this view it only increments the 'view' count by 1 for a single item in my DB. So when i try to get to a 2nd item it does not increment that view, even though it is a unique pk.